# Numpy sampling from a 2d numpy array of probabilities

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array of probabilities, `p` that sum to 1.0:

```
p = np.array([[0.05, 0.05, 0.1 , 0.  ],
              [0.4 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.2 ]])
```

I want to have a function that samples an index from the 2d array `p` based on the probabilities. For example, I should return `[1,0]` with a probability of `0.4` or `[0,2]` with a probability of `0.1`.

If I call the function `sample(p)` which takes the 2d probability array p.
Then with the 2d `p` array as I've defined above I could expect indices anywhere from `[0,0]` to `[1,3]` but not including `[0,3]` as that has a probability of `0` of appearing:

```
sample(p)
>> [1,0]
sample(p)
>> [0,2]
sample(p)
>> [1,0]
sample(p)
>> [1,3]
```

Normally I would use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) however it only accepts 1D array probabilities. Is there a way that I can extend this to work for 2d probability arrays **of any size** .

Comment: Would you please elaborate on the example? I am not really following what is happening there.

Comment: @norok2 I've added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.unravel_index()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html#numpy.ravel_multi_index), together with `np.random.choice()` on the result of `np.arange()` with the `.ravel()` (or `.flatten()`) probability.

For example:

```
p = np.array([[0.05, 0.05, 0.1 , 0.  ],
              [0.4 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.2 ]])


def sample_index(p):
    i = np.random.choice(np.arange(p.size), p=p.ravel())
    return np.unravel_index(i, p.shape)

np.random.seed(0)
x = [sample_index(p) for _ in range(10)]
print(x)
# [(1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make your array flat first :)

```
p = np.array([[0.05, 0.05, 0.1 , 0.  ],
          [0.4 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.2 ]])
r = np.random.choice(np.arange(8), p=p.ravel())
```

Ravel returns a view of your array in a one dimensional form.

```
p.ravel().shape
> (8,)
```

Just checking if its working properly:

```
r = np.random.choice(np.arange(8), size=10000, p=p.ravel())
np.unique(r, return_counts=True)
> (array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([ 530,  523,  968, 4014, 1012,  944, 2009]))
```